# Wait until refresh of all queries is done

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

```
Sub WaitForQueriesToRefresh()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim refreshComplete As Boolean
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    refreshComplete = False
    
    ' Set the interval to check the query status (in seconds)
    Const CheckIntervalInSeconds As Long = 5
    
    ' Loop to continuously check the query status until all queries are refreshed
    Do While Not refreshComplete
        refreshComplete = True ' Assume all queries are refreshed initially
        
        ' Check each query table in the workbook
        For Each qt In wb.Sheets(1).QueryTables
            If qt.Refreshing Then
                refreshComplete = False
                Exit For ' Exit the loop if any query is still refreshing
            End If
        Next qt
        
        ' If not all queries are refreshed, wait for the specified interval
        If Not refreshComplete Then
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, CheckIntervalInSeconds)
        End If
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "All queries have been refreshed."
End Sub
```

is this query accurate

Comment: Prior to this, have you tried turning off refreshing in background and using DoEvents? I'm not familiar with `.Refreshing` but from what I just read in documentation and the rest of your code, this should technically work. Did you have issues/encounter errors while using this code?